# Windows 8 App and Windows Phone App Submission

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am a little confused with the two apps, Windows 8 (which run only on Windows 8 OS?) and Windows Phone Apps.

Based on the marketing I heard around windows 8, I assumed an app available on Windows 8 would automatically be available on windows phone?

I am assuming this is not the case after searching around, because I see a windows app store (which I assume only includes windows 8 apps), and the windows phone.

Assuming my assumptions are correct, do you need to buy a developer licence for both windows 8 app store and windows phone store?

Is it as simple as submitting your windows 8 app that was created through windows phone, or is there additional configuration or development that needs to be done?  Assuming that you don't care about resolutions or functionality.

Thanks for any clarification.

*Additional question,

Where does Windows tablets running windows RT and or non RT fall into all this?  Are they windows apps I'm assuming?

Comment: You can share quite a bit of code, but they're still two quite different beasts with separate stores/developer licenses. Don't count on things running smoothly from one platform to the other without modifications.

Answer (score 2):

Hope it helps you. As the store licences are unified (WP8 and Windows 8), the development remains different http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/11/06/unifying-developer-registration-windows-and-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct Both the platforms need seperate Developer Accounts one for the Windows Store Apps and one For the Windows Phone Apps..and yes both the Apps are different you have to develop both the Apps Separately and submit them to the respective market separately only then would it be available in the respective markets.

Answer (score 0):

Separate Developer Accounts for the Windows Store Apps and Phone are no longer required.  If you have a App Store account, you should now see that you can register up to 3 phones without a separate registration process.

IF you have a developer account, VS2013, and a windows 8 phone plugged into USB, an easy way to be guided through the process is to create a new project and select a W8 Phone sample. Specify that you want to debug using a Device (as opposed to an emulator).  You will get a Device is not registered for development dialog with a link to instructions.

As mentioned in other post, things have been streamlined so W8 and W8 phone mostly overlap APIs, and you can probably use the same source, but will need build separate outputs.